# VBA Access - FindFirst Null Value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to findfirst null value on the following code. I could just use where in the select but it will remove the non null values. I want to keep the whole recordset so I can report back to the user which row is null using rs.AbsolutePosition. I've basically set it up to compare the users entered information in the temp table against another table. If the matching string is in there it appears, otherwise should be null on the recordset.

```
strSQL = "SELECT Tbl_Temp.ID, Tbl_List.String FROM Tbl_Temp LEFT JOIN Tbl_List ON Tbl_Temp.string = Tbl_List.string"
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
strIsN = "IsNull(string)"

rs.FindFirst strIsN
    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "no null values"
    Do While Not rs.NoMatch
        MsgBox "Found null" & rs.AbsolutePosition
        rs.FindNext strIsN
    Loop
    rs.FindNext strIsN
End If
```

It basically does nothing right now. Doesn't even trigger an error or no match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `strIsN = "[String] Is Null"`

Comment: Does not work, doesn't even trigger the no match. When I just create a select query with that SQL there are 3 results, 2 are null.

Comment: I also tried IsNull(string) = 'True' as the string, which procc'd the no match but still doesn't work

Comment: Keep in mind that AbsolutePosition is 0 based and will change depending on how you sort your recordset.  I'd think it would be better to return the Primary Key value as that is unique to that record & won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Your code indentation is off and fooled both you and me.

This is what you want - you were missing the `Else`.

```
RS.FindFirst strIsN
If RS.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "no null values"
Else
    Do While Not RS.NoMatch
        Debug.Print "Found null " & RS.AbsolutePosition
        RS.FindNext strIsN
    Loop
End If
```

Please read [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx), stepping through your code would have found the issue instantly.

Both `"IsNull(string)"` and `"[String] Is Null"` will work, but `"[String] Is Null"` will probably perform a little better.

Comment: Ah thanks! Can't believe I did that and posted it. All my other finds had else. I'm going to blame being tired.